# кириллица не записывается в json файл

Tags: php, json

Есть форма. С нее получаем данные POST'ом. Эти данные записываем в json файл.
Проблема: кириллица ни в какую не хочет записываться. Дамп массива в PHP нормальный - что вписали, то и выдает [image: php vardump]

а вот в json файле лежит вместо кириллицы null.[image: json]
PHP 5.3

```
$user = array(
    'name'=> $user_name,
    'lastname'=> $user_lastname,
    'mail'=> $user_mail,
    'birthday'=> $user_date,
    'phone'=> $user_phone,
    'cardnumber'=> $user_cardnumb,
);
$json = file_get_contents('card.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true); 
$json[] = $user;
$json = json_encode($json);
file_put_contents('card.json', $json);
}
```

Менял версию на 5.4, вставлял второй параметр $json = json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); - в json файле стоят простые скобки "", где должна быть кириллица.Кстати, почему-то дамп массива в PHP 5.4 с той же кириллицей выдает "", а латиницу нормально выводит

Answer (score 2):

PHP функция `json_encode` работает [только с UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6607083) ([соответствующее место](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.4/ext/json/json.c#L423) в исходнике не сопровождается комментариями, а в последующих версиях и `warning` убран)

Обратите внимание на `string(4) "Иван"`. Число в скобках - длина строки в байтах. Это однозначно не UTF8, для которого 4 кириллических символа занимают 8 байт, а что-то однобайтовое.

Поэтому вам необходимо или переводить код на использование UTF8 (что предпочтительнее) или конвертировать все строки в UTF8 перед использованием `json_encode` и, соответственно, обратно конвертировать после `json_decode`

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, то мне необходимо сделать так:
    $user_name = mb_convert_encoding($user_name, "UTF-8", "window-1251"); 
    $json = file_get_contents('card.json');
    $json = json_decode($json, true); 
    $user['name'] = mb_convert_encoding($user['name'], "window-1251", "UTF-8");
    $json[] = $user;
    $json = json_encode($json);
    file_put_contents('card.json', $json);
Но так записывается false

Comment: если сделать наоборот - тоже не работает.

Comment: Исправил на Windows-1251, дамп массива выдает ""

Comment: я не понимаю, что вы приведённым кодом пытались сделать.

Comment: Я принял поле "Имя" с формы, конвертировал эту строку перед json_encode в UTF-8, а перед json_decode в Windows-1251. Дамп выдает ""

Comment: А теперь что вижу я: невнятные манипуляции с $user_name, не используемой в дальнейшем. Прочитали json, не проверили, а что же там прочитали, невнятные манипуляции по конвертированию в 1251 (используя скорей всего исходную строку в 1251, но утверждая что это была utf8 - что в результате - да хз), попробовали это непонятно что перезаписать в файлик. В общем - полный бардак и 0 понимания происходящего. Потому и мой вопрос - а что пытались сделать-то?